# Bitvise SFTP server On-upload command batch file

Tags: sftp, bitvise

I am trying to get bitvise SFTP server to run a batch file once a file is uploaded Should the command just be:

```
cmd/c D:\DataImport\data.bat
```

[image: IMG:]

Do I need to configure something in the working directory?
How can I debug the command to see if there were errors in execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space between `cmd` and `/c`.

---

*(Also it looks like the execution is delayed)*